# How to create a console that act as a server?

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, javascript, console

I am a computer science student working on my capstone project. My team is building a vehicle renting system. In this system, user can book and rent a car they like on a specific date range. We are trying to make a "server" that will auto send out notification/email to users days before their renting expired.

Currently, we are able to make it with JavaScript and PHP by setting a timeout function by querying the database every minutes to check for the upcoming expiry date. We kinda of think this is quite stupid because we will have to open a web page in a browser for this to work.

We get to know from our professor that we are able to create something like a "console" in a remote PC that at as a server that will do the job we want. But we have no idea how and our professor is not helping us too much since its a milestone project.

We build our project using JavaScript & PHP for our frontend & backend. While for our DB we are using MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the professor meant a "console *program*" – as in, a program that you'd start through Terminal or Command Prompt, for example.

There is nothing particularly special about such programs (except that, of course, they're meant to output plain text and not HTML); indeed, in most languages they're literally the most basic type of program that one starts with.

It is possible to write console-based programs in PHP as well – for example, if you have a .php script that contains `<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>` and you run it through Terminal as `php Hello.php`, that's a console program.

Console-based programs can then be started either on schedule to perform periodic tasks (Linux servers have the 'cron' facility, Windows servers have Task Scheduler), or as a "service" to run continuously from server startup to shutdown. Once you have a script that can be run through console, the server administrator can easily add a 'cron' job to have it run e.g. hourly.

Several popular PHP-based applications, such as Moodle or SimpleSAMLphp, indeed come with a few .php scripts specifically meant to be run through console, either manually for administrative tasks, or through cron for periodic jobs (such as notifications).